# Babel presets ordering is occurring run-time error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I got an error `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'` on IE(chrome was good)
and reordered babel presets fixing the error.

You know babel presets loaded by backward.
I wondered how presets ordering affects the result and what is best practice presets ordering.

**Issue**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

**Fixed**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```